# Ray tracing, translucent sphere has a dot in centre

Tags: transparency, raytracing, translucency

I'm building a ray tracer as an assignment. I'm trying to get refraction working for spheres and I got it half-working. The problem is I can't get rid of the black dot in the centre of the sphere

[image]

This is the code for the intersection:

```
double a = rayDirection.DotProduct(rayDirection);
double b = rayOrigin.VectAdd(sphereCenter.Negative()).VectMult(2).DotProduct(rayDirection);
double c = rayOrigin.VectAdd(sphereCenter.Negative()).DotProduct(rayOrigin.VectAdd(sphereCenter.Negative())) - (radius * radius);
double discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;

if (discriminant >= 0)
{
    // the ray intersects the sphere
    // the first root
    double root1 = ((-1 * b - sqrt(discriminant)) / 2.0 * a) - 0.000001;
    double root2 = ((-1 * b + sqrt(discriminant)) / 2.0 * a) - 0.000001;

    if (root1 > 0.00001)
    {
        // the first root is the smallest positive root
        return root1;
    }
    else
    {
        // the second root is the smallest positive root    
        return root2;
    }
}
else
{
    // the ray missed the sphere
    return -1;
}
```

This is the code responsible for computing the direction of the new refracted ray:

```
double n1 = refractionRay.GetRefractiveIndex();
double n2 = sceneObjects.at(indexOfWinningObject)->GetMaterial().GetRefractiveIndex();

if (n1 == n2)
{
    // ray inside the same material, means that it is going to be refracted outside, 
    n2 = 1.000293;
}

double n  = n1 / n2;

Vect I = refractionRay.GetRayDirection();
Vect N = sceneObjects.at(indexOfWinningObject)->GetNormalAt(intersectionPosition);

double cosTheta1 = -N.DotProduct(I);
// we need the normal pointing towards the side the ray is coming from
if (cosTheta1 < 0) 
{
    N = N.Negative();
    cosTheta1 = -N.DotProduct(I);
}

double cosTheta2 = sqrt(1 - (n * n) * (1 - (cosTheta1 * cosTheta1)));
Vect refractionDirection = I.VectMult(n).VectAdd(N.VectMult(n * cosTheta1 - cosTheta2));


Ray newRefractionRay(intersectionPosition.VectAdd(refractionDirection.VectMult(0.001)), refractionDirection, n2, refractionRay.GetRemainingIntersections());
```

When creating the new refracting ray, I tried adding the direction times a small value to the intersection position to make the origin of this new ray inside the sphere. The size of the black dot changes if I change that small value. If I make it too big the margins of the sphere start turning black as well.

If I add colour to the object it looks like this:

[image]

And if make that small constant bigger (0.1) this happens:

[image]

Is there a special condition I should take into account? Thank you!

Comment: Note that you also have one on the reflection in the green sphere too. If it is relevant, I believe that the foreground sphere is colorless and clear rather than reflective?

Comment: I'd suggest checking your refraction equations first - the sphere intersection looks ostensibly valid (and that's supported by the correct rendering of the opaque spheres in the scene).

Comment: also, there shouldn't be any need to subtract that epsilon factor from the two roots so long as you ensure that the value of the roots found does exceed epsilon.  These factors are only needed to ensure that newly generated rays starting on the surface of the sphere don't self intersect the sphere again.

Comment: FWIW, my implementation is here - https://github.com/raybellis/RRT/blob/master/primitive/sphere.cpp

Comment: oh, and your shadows look odd.  They shouldn't be smaller than the balls that cast them.

Comment: Singularities at poles are common in ray tracing. Could you be dividing by ~ `0` when `a` is small? Try highlighting NaN pixels in some color other than black.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak, you're right about the shadows, they seem a bit odd. Also I've added the code that computes the new refracted ray. Hope it clarifies the issue.

Comment: @JaredHoberock good call - that test should be `> 0`, not `>=`

Comment: That said, it appears to be something to do with when the incoming ray hits the ball dead center (more or less).   AFAICR that's not related to the discriminant.

Comment: @JaredHoberock I've just tested `a` and it doesn't get smaller than 0.01.

Comment: do you have any other constants or fudge factors in your code that when changed vary the size of the dot?   I could understand a single pixel coming out that way, but IMHO it's odd that you get a whole circle.

Comment: also, check the point at which that black colour is assigned.  Are you perhaps hitting your ray bounce limit only in cases where the ray comes in at 90' (and therefore doesn't get bent), goes straight through, hits the opposite side and comes right back out again?

Comment: @Alnitak I've posted new images of the same object with colour assigned to it and also what happens if that constant is too big.

Comment: get rid of the constant that's subtracted in the lines `double root1 = ...` (and for `root2` too).  When the new ray starts on the sphere it should get a distance of 0, and will therefore be ignored by the following `if (root1 > 0.00001)` test.

Comment: Thank you @Alnitak, the refraction now works I think, but I have another problem now. I have tiny black dots everywhere inside the sphere.

Comment: I'll try to fix this

Comment: @Alnitak post what you just said as the answer, so you can get points for it.

Comment: I've managed to solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the epsilon factors that you subtract when you calculate the two roots:

```
double root1 = ((-1 * b - sqrt(discriminant)) / 2.0 * a);
double root2 = ((-1 * b + sqrt(discriminant)) / 2.0 * a);
```

In my experience the only place you need a comparison against epsilon is when checking whether the found root is along the path of the ray and not at its origin, per your:

```
if (root1 > 0.00001)
```

NB: you could eke out a little more performance by only doing the square root calculation once, and also by only calculating `root2` if `root1 <= epsilon`

Answer (score 0):

My ray-sphere intersection computation didn't involve an epsilon, but I did offset my reflection and my refraction rays to avoid a double intersection, and by lowering this epsilon value, I was able to squeeze my hole smaller until it went out of existence.